# Haskell match construct analogous to F# type-test pattern?

Tags: haskell, types, casting, f#, pattern-matching

#### tl;dr

If I understand correctly, Haskell does not have subtypes in the way that F# does. Thus I expect that it does not have a type-test pattern for matching, like F#. Does it have any analogous constructs that can be used for metaprogramming?

#### Case Study

I have an [F# project](https://github.com/PolyglotSymposium/void) in which I have decoupled modules that talk through a messaging mechanism. Recently I have been wondering what this code would look like, or if it would even be possible to write it this way, if I were to port it to Haskell.

The basic idea is this. A message is a type that inherits from the message interface:

```ml
type Message = interface end
```

A handler is a function that takes a specific subtype of `Message` and returns a `Message`:

```ml
type Handle<'TMsg when 'TMsg :> Message> = 'TMsg -> Message
```

There is a `Bus` with a `publish` method that distributes a message to its internal channels. There is one `Channel<'TMsg>` per message type, and these are added dynamically when a handler is registered. The bus publishes all messages to all channels, and if it is of the wrong type, the channel simply returns an empty sequence:

```ml
type Channel<'TIn when 'TIn :> Message>(...) = ...
    interface Channel with
        member x.publish (message : Message) =
            match message with
            | :? 'TIn as msg ->
                Seq.map (fun handle -> handle msg) _handlers
                |> Seq.filter (fun msg -> msg <> noMessage)
            | _ -> Seq.empty
```

Ultimately what I'm doing here is dynamic metaprogramming which allows me to have strongly typed messages that still get passed through the same machinery in the middle. I am not as up on Haskell as F#, and I can't figure out how to do this in Haskell.

Am I right that Haskell has no `match... with... :?... as...` construct? Does it have a similar construct or another approach to this sort of metaprogramming that you can solve this sort of problem with? Is there some sort of box/unbox mechanism?

Comment: I'm not particularly knowledgeable in F#, but does [Data.Dynamic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) mostly do what you want?

Comment: @AlexR yes, perhaps so. I will have to play with it to know for sure, but it looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell is designed so that types can be completely erased at runtime. That is, when an implementation stores a value of a type `T` in memory, there is no need to tag it with some label saying "this is of type `T`".

This gives nice parametricity guarantees in return, also referred to as "free theorems". For instance, a function having a polymorphic type

```hs
f :: a -> a
```

*must* return its argument or fail to terminate. That is, we know that `f=id` (if we know it terminates).

Concretely, this implies that there's no way to write something like

```hs
f :: a -> a
f x = if a == Int then x+1 else x
```

If one wishes to do such a thing, one can manually add type tags through the `Data.Typeable` class:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, GADTs, TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Typeable

f :: forall a . Typeable a => a -> a
f x = case eqT :: Maybe (a :~: Int) of
      Just Refl -> x+1
      Nothing   -> x
```

Note how the type changed, and now has a constraint. It has to, since the effect of the function violates the free theorem of the unconstrained polymorphic type.

So, if you really need to perform runtime type checks, carry around a `Typeable` constraint. Note that this is possibly too much general. If you know you have a small amount of types, probably you can use a sum type instead, and use plain pattern matching on constructors to test for the type:

```hs
data T = TInt Int
       | TChar Char

f :: T -> T
f (TInt i) = TInt (i+1)
f (TChar c) = TChar c
```

Answer (score 8):

Apologies for answering your question with [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)), but I wouldn't be doing it like that in F#, either.

That `Message` interface is what's known as a [Marker Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern), and while this is contentious, I consider it a code smell in any language that supports annotations (*attributes*, in .NET).

A Marker Interface doesn't do anything, so you can achieve the same behaviour without it.

I wouldn't design a messaging system like that in C#, because the Marker Interface adds nothing, except the illusion that a message is somehow 'typed'.

I wouldn't design a messaging system like that in F#, because there's a better, safer, strongly typed alternative in F#:

```
type UserEvent =
    | UserCreated of UserCreated
    | EmailVerified of EmailVerified
    | EmailChanged of EmailChanged
```

This specifies clearly that the set of events is finite, and well-known. With that, you get **compile-time checking** instead of run-time checking.

(See [here for the full example](https://github.com/GreanTech/AtomEventStore/wiki/Reading-events#interpreting-events-with-f-using-a-discriminated-union).)

Such a Discriminated Union is easy to translate to Haskell:

```
data UserEvent = UserCreated UserCreatedData
               | EmailVerified EmailVerifiedData
               | EmailChanged EmailChangedData
```

Comment: Possibly, his approach was inspired by atoms in languages such as erlang, where messages typically look like ``{foo, 42; bar, { baz, 33 } }``.

Comment: @BitTickler Possibly. Isn't Erlang dynamically typed?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason I've used a marker interface is that I don't want to have one overall discriminated union for all messages. I want to be able to split messages across assemblies. Or am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: @KeithPinson You aren't misunderstanding my suggestion, but if you want to make groups of messages (e.g. to deal with various bounded contexts), you can define a discriminated union for each group.

Comment: `IMessage` is NOT a marker interface. It is not used as annotation.